# Simple get API call in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web

I have a url to which I need to make a get call. The url returns the following JSON response when run in POSTMAN.

```
{
  "status": true,
   "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "suggestion": "shirt"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "suggestion": "jeans"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "suggestion": "puma"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "suggestion": "spykar"
    }
  ],
  "lastPageNumber": 0
}
```

I need to get the "suggestion" key's value and append to my list.
Following is my code to get the data and append its values to a list as shown.

```
jQuery.getJSON( url, function( response ) { 
    $.each(response.data ,function() {
        $.each(this, function (key, value) {
            if(key=="suggestion") {             
              $('#suggestions').append('<li class="suggestItem">' 
                                       + '<a>' + value + '</a>' + '</li>'});
            }
        );
    });
});
```

And this is the ul to which I have to append these list items.

```
  <ul id="suggestions" style="position: absolute; list-style-type: none;">
```

However, I do not seem to get any data in response or maybe I am not traversing through the JSON array correctly. So, I need help in whether I have written the right code or not.

Also additional information:
I am running this project on localhost and the url is something http://example.anotherExample.net so does this also affect (I read something about cross domain in ajax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like following

```
$.each(obj.data, function(){
  $('#suggestions').append('<li class="suggestItem">' + '<a>' + this.suggestion + '</a>' + '</li>');
});
```

Comment: Tried this. Couldn't get it to work. Please see the additional information I have added.

Comment: Can you please log response and tell what is in it?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://vindotrial.cloudapp.net/api/fetchSuggestions. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
So is this cross domain issue? I am new to jQuery and api calls.

Comment: Yes. This is cross domain issue.